token=2024-04-28T14%3A00%3A00%2B8%3A00Z brings older changes too and get sensitivity label from Graph
I am trying to get changes to sensitivity labels.
Using a date time token in:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/root/delta?token=2024-04-28T14%3A00%3A00%2B8%3A00Z&$select=lastModifiedDateTime,name

I get the correct 2 changes but also 2 modified a month ago.
I am not sure my call is correct for "Changes made after datetime"
Also How do I retrieve the sensitivity label?
